# Firefox Back button not working as expected: javascript displayed instead of html

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, history.js

I am using History.js to make my ajax pages bookmarkable and to have the expected back/forward browser button experience. In Safari all works great but in Firefox 6 if I leave my site and then go back using hte back button I get the javascript instead of the page:

1. go to mysite.com/user/1/post_board
2. click on post filter, address changes to mysite.com/user/1/post_board?filter=one
3. enter google.com in address bar
4. push the back button
5. I see the javascript loaded at step 2

What is going? What I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
//  Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(e)
    {
        var state = History.getState();
        eval(state.data.function_rest + "("+JSON.stringify(state)+");");        
        History.log(state);
    });


$('.message_filter').bind('click', function() 
    {
        History.pushState({"function_rest":"restore_post_board_widget"}, document.title, this.href);
        return false
    });

function restore_post_board_widget(state)
{   
    $.getScript(state.url);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Not another use of eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!). :/

Comment: Does the url `mysite.com/user/1/post_board?filter=one` always return HTML?  Or does it sometimes return JavaScript?

Comment: @Shef: I am open to suggestion on how to handle the history management. Using eval allows quite a bit of flexibility but again I am a total newbie to Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340906/whats-the-recommended-way-to-rebuild-a-page-from-the-browser-history-history-j

Answer (score 2):

just add:

window.onunload = function(){};

this is where I got the answer:

[After travelling back in Firefox history, JavaScript won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run)

Comment: That's the *worst* solution to your problem, it degrades browser performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194095/differences-between-chrome-and-firefox-reloading-a-page-running-a-javascript-gam/7200707#7200707 for the other options.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but even after reading the question you pointed to I do not see any other alternative. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks.